# What is the curl_setopt equivalent of exec('curl -k ...')

Tags: php, curl

I am trying duplicate the functionality of this command:

```
exec('curl -k -d "pameters=here" https://apiurlhere.com', $output);
```

with curl_exec():

```
$url =  'https://apiurlhere.com?parameters=here';
$ci = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$response = curl_exec($ci);
curl_close ($ci);
print_r($response);
```

I have been trying the different options found in the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), and thought it was CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, but it still failed (response comes back empty).

The URL i'm posting to uses SNI which is causing cURL to fail when the SSL cert returns a different host name than it's expecting.

Is there a curl_setopt equivalent to -k?

Comment: That's the right option. Use `curl_error()` to determine the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Using curl_error() was a good idea, but there was no error being thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE)` is the equivalent of `-k` on the command line (which you shouldn't really use, since it makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks).

Your problem here is that you're assuming that `-d "pameters=here"` is equivalent to putting these parameters in the URL query like this `https://apiurlhere.com?parameters=here`.

This isn't the case, see documentation for `-d`:

> (HTTP)  Sends  the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
>   filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause
>   curl to pass the data to
>   the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

You should probably use `POSTFIELDS` for this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("parameters" => "here"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that :

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php